# multiple react state updates renders only the last update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I made a little function to add custom alerts to the state array, and the view renders them. The problem is, if i call the function twice in a row, the first alert is rendered only for a moment, and then its replaced with the second alert. When i call the method with a mouse click, the function works correctly.

I have tried to apply some waiting before pushing to the array list, but no luck with that.

```js
const Element = () => {
  const [alerts, setAlerts] = React.useState([])

  const addAlert = (data) => {
        setAlerts([...alerts, <CustomAlert key={alerts.length} message={data.message} color={data.color} />])
    }

  return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={() => {
                    // this renders only the last state update.
                    addAlert({message: "test", color: "error"}); 
                    addAlert({message: "2", color: "error"})
                }
            }>
           add alert button 
        </button>
      <div>
        {alerts}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React updates the state [asynchronously](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). This means when you are updating the state 2 times in a row, accessing the value of `alerts` directly might not have the latest inserted item. You should use a function instead when calling `setAlerts`:

```
const [alerts, setAlerts] = React.useState([]);

  const addAlert = (data) => {
    setAlerts((prevAlerts) => {
      const newAlerts = [...prevAlerts];
      newAlerts.push(
        <CustomAlert
          key={alerts.length}
          message={data.message}
          color={data.color}
        />
      );
      return newAlerts;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          // this renders only the last state update.
          addAlert({ message: "test", color: "error" });
          addAlert({ message: "2", color: "error" });
        }}
      >
        add alert button
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

`alerts` in your code refers to the value of the current render in both case so your addAlert won't work. To fix this, you can use the setter version with a function:

```
setAlerts(currentAlerts => [...currentAlters, <CustomAlert key={alerts.length} message={data.message} color={data.color} />])
```